# Flutter GetX: Animation with GetxController

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-getx

I'm trying GetX for my new project and tried to use AnimationController which is inspired [this comment](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/733#issuecomment-717550205). Everything works fine with default value for `Tween -> blur & spread` & `AnimationController -> duration`.

What I'm doing:

1: Created an `widget` with corresponding `controller` (controller is binded through `initialBinding` of GetMaterialApp).

```
GetMaterialApp(
  ...
  initialBinding: AnimationBinding()
  ...
);

class AnimationBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<AnimationController>(
      () => AnimationController(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomAnimatedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<LogoAnimationController>(
      builder: (_) {
        return Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 150,
          child: Text('for demo only, originally its not text widget'),
          ...
          remaining code that uses `_.animation.value`
          ...
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class AnimationController extends GetxController with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  Animation animation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);

    animation = Tween(begin: 2.0, end: 15.0)
        .animate(_animationController)
          ..addListener(() => update());
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();

    _animationController.dispose();
  }
}
```

2: Used this `widget` inside `view`.

```
child: CustomAnimatedWidget();
```

Till now, everything is working fine. But I want to update `blur, spread & duration`, with:
updating `CustomAnimatedWidget`:

```
final double blur;
  final double spread;
  final int duration;
  CustomAnimatedWidget({this.blur, this.spread, this.duration});

  ...
      builder: (_) => ...
      ...
      initState: (s) {
        _.blur.value = blur;
        _.spread.value = spread;
        _.duration.value = duration;
      },
  ...
```

updating `AnimationController`:

```
Rx<double> blur = 2.0.obs;
  Rx<double> spread = 15.0.obs;
  Rx<int> duration = 2.obs;
```

and using/calling the `CustomAnimationWidget` using:

```
child: CustomAnimatedWidget(duration: 4, blur: 2, spread: 10);
```

but don't know how to use it with `_animationController` & `_animation` because they are called in `onInit`.

Please share your solutions, thanks.

Comment: Would you can share full code of your solution to change it and solve?

Comment: @HosseinHadi I already posted the code that is required to understand and answer. Please let me know which part is not missing...

Comment: @HosseinHadi by the way, I moved to `StatefulWidget` from `GetxController` and get the actual result

Comment: I've worked with GetX and do all animations with it , so it is possible to do that . But the question is some obfuscated for me on many places. So if you you want a good answer please make a minimal code that regenerate what you want and share that , I mean share the view fully , and controller fully , and usage of them fully ...

Comment: But up to now , as it seems , you are using 'Rx' values with GetBuilder . This is not a good practice and you would not be able to get the answer .

Comment: You need not to share all of your code or all of your application as well ! But this is a common practice in stack overflow to share a minimal code that regenerates the issue. There is , always for me , some small changes in working with GetX that solved my problem.

Comment: @HosseinHadi Please let me know which part is not understandable or missing...

Comment: Why are you using `Rx<double>` ? Is there any `Obx` or `GetX` widget in your code ? You wrote `remaining code that uses _.animation.value` in the `GetBuilder` (while the `.value` must be used in the `Obx` or `GetX` widget); this means that you are misinterpreting and confusing reactive vs not-reactive state management.

Comment: You must change any `Rx<double>` to `double` itself  (and other `Rx`s to themselves type) to work properly in `GetBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

I Extended `GetxController` with `GetTickerProviderStateMixin` and then make a `AnimationController` and `CurvedAnimation` by code below:

```
late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: false);

  late final Animation<double> animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.ease,
  );
```

After that i just created object of my CustomGetxController like this final `_customController = Get.put(CustomGetxController());` then i called it like this:

```
 FadeTransition(
            opacity: driverController.animation,
            child:const Text('My Flashing Text')
          ),
```

Comment: I have done `class MyClass extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin` and when I use `this` for the `vsync` I get `Invalid reference to 'this' expression`. 

Comment: @CliftonLabrum, I have done **`with GetTickerProviderStateMixin`**